# MySql TIMESTAMPDIFF with float value

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

hoping you all are doing well, I'm working with MySql and using a TIMESTAMPDIFF function like this:

TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, 07:00:00, 16:30:00) and this return 9

So my question is, there's a way to get the return as 9.5 (nine and a half hours)?

Thanks!

I've already tried using TIMEDIFF and doing the substract but it returns 9.3

Comment: Have you tried `cast`?